# RVO and std::vector implementations

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, rvo, nrvo

I wrote the code below to check that popular C++03 compilers implement RVO whenever possible. 
(See my related question about RVO [Return value optimization: ho can I avoid copy construction of huge STL containers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33562810/return-value-optimization-ho-can-i-avoid-copy-construction-of-huge-stl-containe)).

As far as I understand the short answer is no. But I'm not sure I understand.

I have the following five questions about the std::vector implementation of clang gcc and VS9, 
read the code and the output below:

1. Why is compiler C Fun1 copying twice the vector?
2. Why both compiler B and C always construct at least one non-requested element?
3. Why this non requested element is made twice with compiler C Fun2?
4. Why reserving space yields one more non requested element for both compilers B and C?
5. Is all this standard compliant?
6. Bonus question: Does all this corresponds to user's expectations?

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

#define SIZE (3) 

class NRVO{
public:
  NRVO() : name_(-1){}
  ~NRVO(){
    std::cout << "Destroy "<< name_ << "\n";
  }
  void set_name(){name_ = counter++;}
private:
  int name_;
  static int counter; 
};

int NRVO::counter = 0;

std::vector<NRVO> fun1(){
  std::vector<NRVO> vec(SIZE);  
  for(std::vector<NRVO>::iterator v_it = vec.begin();
      v_it != vec.end();
      ++v_it){
    v_it->set_name();
  }
  return vec;
}

void fun2(std::vector<NRVO>& vec){
  vec.clear();
  vec.resize(SIZE);  
  for(std::vector<NRVO>::iterator v_it = vec.begin();
      v_it != vec.end();
      ++v_it){
    v_it->set_name();
  }
  return;
}

int main(){
  {
    std::vector<NRVO> myNrvo1;
    std::cout << "Fun1\n";
    myNrvo1 = fun1();
    assert(myNrvo1.size()==SIZE);
  }
  {
    std::vector<NRVO> myNrvo2;
    std::cout << "Fun2\n";
    fun2(myNrvo2);
    assert(myNrvo2.size()==SIZE);
  }
  {
    std::vector<NRVO> myNrvo3;
    myNrvo3.reserve(SIZE);
    std::cout << "Fun3\n";
    fun2(myNrvo3);
    assert(myNrvo3.size()==SIZE);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output with popular C++11 compiler A

```
Fun1
Destroy 0
Destroy 1
Destroy 2
Fun2
Destroy 3
Destroy 4
Destroy 5
Fun3 
Destroy 6
Destroy 7
Destroy 8
```

Output with popular C++03 compiler B

```
Fun1
Destroy -1
Destroy 0
Destroy 1
Destroy 2
Destroy 0
Destroy 1
Destroy 2
Fun2
Destroy -1
Destroy 3
Destroy 4
Destroy 5
Fun3 
Destroy -1
Destroy -1
Destroy 6
Destroy 7
Destroy 8
```

Output with popular C++03 compiler C

```
Fun1
Destroy -1
Destroy 0
Destroy 1
Destroy 2
Destroy 0
Destroy 1
Destroy 2
Destroy 0
Destroy 1
Destroy 2
Fun2
Destroy -1
Destroy -1
Destroy 3
Destroy 4
Destroy 5
Fun3
Destroy -1
Destroy -1
Destroy -1
Destroy 6
Destroy 7
Destroy 8
```

Comment: 1) I suspect compiler C to use a temporary. `vec` is copied to temporary; temporary is assigned to `myNrvo1`. You might test this by ignoring the return value of `fun1`: `std::cout << "Fun1\n"; (void) fun1();`

Comment: @OP : Do you see copies happening ?

Comment: @Arunmu: we see copies' destruction ;)

Comment: Did you build release builds for all of these compilers? To aid in debugging, it's nice for temporaries to be there, so debug builds will often not do such optimisations.

Comment: Try 'std::vector<NRVO> myNrvo1 = fun1();' in main.

Comment: Without C++11 turned out, g++(4.8.x) in my case misses out to do direct initialization when the vector is instantiated in advance i.e before call site